# imported sklearn but can't call sklearn.linear_model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, spyder

I have sklearn installed and was able to import sklearn by using the command
    import sklearn

However, I found that submodules of sklearn cannot be called by sklearn.module_name, eg:

```
In [1]: import sklearn

In [2]: sklearn.linear_model
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-e64c575ed22e>", line 1, in <module>
    sklearn.linear_model

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'linear_model'
```

At the same time, I am able to directly import sklearn.linear_model

```
In [3]: import sklearn.linear_model

In [4]: sklearn.linear_model
Out[4]: <module 'sklearn.linear_model' from 
'C:\Users\sng\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\python2\lib\site-
packages\sklearn\linear_model\__init__.pyc'>
```

The above is not true, for example in matplotlib:

```
In [5]: import matplotlib

In [6]: matplotlib.pyplot
Out[6]: <module 'matplotlib.pyplot' from 
'C:\Users\sng\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\python2\lib\site-
packages\matplotlib\pyplot.pyc'>
```

I am curious what's going on here? Is the package sklearn different from the others? My IDE is Spyder for python 2.7

Comment: Try `from sklearn import *` then `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Its just that when you call `import matplotlib` it imports pyplot internally and hence you can use it as it is without importing the `pyplot` specifically.

Have a look at [the source of the file](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/__init__.py#L125) which is imported when you execute `import matplotlib`. It has some lines like:

```
...
...
from matplotlib.cbook import (
    _backports, mplDeprecation, dedent, get_label, sanitize_sequence)
from matplotlib.compat import subprocess
from matplotlib.rcsetup import defaultParams, validate_backend, cycler
...
...
```

Some of these imports from `cbook`, `compat`, `rcsetup` I am sure are in turn importing `pyplot` or classes from pyplot somewhere.

This is not the case with sklearn. Look at the source of `__init__.py` of sklearn]([https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/**init**.py#L15](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/__init__.py#L15))

It has only the following imports:

```
import sys
import re
import warnings
import os
from contextlib import contextmanager as _contextmanager
import logging
```

Which in no way are using `linear_model` hence the error.

You can verify this behaviour by importing a related package like this:

```
import sklearn
import sklearn.svm
```

Now when you execute `sklearn.linear_model`, you will get correct output:

```
<module 'sklearn.linear_model' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/__init__.pyc'>
```

because, this time, at least of the imports defined [in svm init](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/svm/__init__.py#L12) are using (importing) some class of `linear_model` somewhere. And hence the linear_model is available to the system.

Comment: This helps me understand the issue, but could do with some editing to improve the readability of the answer.